# Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id error on creating a case record

Tags: case, assignment-rules

The scenario is, I am Creating a Case record type and then getting this error. When I am doing this I am logged in as a user from the profile which has access to Create, Read and Edit this specific case record type.

I have created an assignment rule and every time this case record is created it is supposed to send out an email notification to the Queue Members. This email notification is sent out every time the case is created as a Salesforce Admin to the QUEUE MEMBERS but when I try to create a case record as this profile user gets this error.

How do I investigate this error in the debug logs in the Developer Console? I am a newbie into Salesforce Development.

Comment: For debugging Apex code,  take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/debugging_diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

`Insufficient access rights on cross-reference id`

The error message itself says that a related object access is missing from the profile.

You might have `Case` access, but there might be lookups related to this case which your profile might not have access too check that.

Comment: I noticed a behaviour when I deselect "Assign using active assignment rules checkbox the record is getting saved". I have also created an active assignment rule. Is there any possibility it could be because of that assignment rule? If Yes, please explain me what is causing this?